# Неправильное поведение semaphore в простейшей задаче

Tags: java, многопоточность, mutex

Только разбираюсь с понятиями mutex-ов и semaphore-ов, потому решил для примера решить простейшую задачу про 5 философов.

---

О самой задаче: есть 5 человек (философов) и стол, вмещающий 2 человека. Необходимо накормить всех людей и при этом не создать конфликтной ситуации, когда за стол попытаются сесть 2 человека.

---

Идея решения кажется очень простой: создать *Semaphore* с 2-мя *permit*-ами, а в *run* каждого потока занимается 1 из этих *permit*-ов. После того, как произойдёт задержка (философ ест), место освобождается - отпускается 1 *permit*.

Полный код решения, так как он относительно небольшой:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class MainSemaphore {

    private static class Philosopher extends Thread{
        private Semaphore semaphore;
        static int table_capacity = 0;

        Philosopher(String name, Semaphore semaphore){
            this.setName(name);
            this.semaphore = semaphore;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            try {
                System.out.printf("%s пришёл поесть.\n", getName());
                semaphore.acquire(1);
                table_capacity++;
                System.out.printf("%s сел за стол. За столом сейчас: %d философов.\n",getName(),table_capacity);
                try {
                    sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                table_capacity--;
                System.out.printf("%s поел и встал из-за стола. За столом сейчас: %d философов.\n",getName(),
                        table_capacity);
                semaphore.release(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                semaphore.release();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(2, true);
        Philosopher ph1 = new Philosopher("Аристотель", sem);
        Philosopher ph2 = new Philosopher("Платон", sem);
        Philosopher ph3 = new Philosopher("Сократ", sem);
        Philosopher ph4 = new Philosopher("Диоген", sem);
        Philosopher ph5 = new Philosopher("Протагор", sem);

        ph1.start();
        ph2.start();
        ph3.start();
        ph4.start();
        ph5.start();

    }
}
```

Увы, на практике идея работает не идеально. Если быть точнее, совершенно не работает. На скриншоте ниже видно, что за столом в какой-то момент сидят 3 философа:
[image: Проблема]
Даже если уменьшить количество мест (*permit*-ов) до одного, найдётся момент, когда за столом окажется 2 (а то и 3) философа!
[image: Проблема 2]
Совершенно не понимаю, в чём может быть проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых `table_capacity` должен быть `AtomicInteger`, ведь там два потока могут одновременно находиться, а во-вторых у вас два `semaphore.release(1);` один в `try`, другой в `finally` и получается, что один ушедший философов полностью освобождает семафор

Comment: Оуф. А я и не заметил, что когда изменял код, оставил .release() в finally{...}.

Comment: Вообще-то задача про философов не так звучит. Там доступны все 5 тарелок, но их нужно кушать двумя приборами, которых всего 5. Поэтому возникает конкуренция за свободную вилку.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець, прошу прощения. Я брал задачку не из надёжного источника, так что ручаться за неё не могу.